How to evaluate 2 variables using bash arithematic in if statement with AND operator in bash shell
I have an alphanumeric string, say something like "XXXX24Y2" from which i have extracted only the numbers and assigned them to 2 variables, say num1 and num2, say num1=24 and num2=2
Now i want to check  (if num1 <=24 and num2 <2); then do something. I have tried all kinds of brackets double, single, square, with quotes around the variable, without etc. I dont get any errors. Its just that bash wont read that if statement.
My code is something like this:
#!/bin/bash
NEW_BR_NAME=$1
TAG=$2
j_name=$3
echo $1 > brname.txt
brname=$(cat brname.txt | cut -c1-8)

if [[ "$3" == "git" ]]; then
   grep -q "ABC3" brname.txt && echo "Its ABC3"
   read num1 num2 <<<${brname//[^0-9]/ }
   echo "num1=$num1 num2=$num2"
   if [[ $num1 <= 24 && $num2 < 2 ]]; then
     echo "something to print"
     exit 1
   fi
fi

My code works perfectly fine till echo "num1=$num1 num2=$num2" but there are no errors and the next if statement is not understood by bash shell. how do i check if $num1 <=24 adn $num2 <2 in this case? what am i doing wrong?

For arithmetic expressions use if (( num1 <= 24 && num2 < 2 )); then. [[ $num1 <= 24...]] is syntactically wrong, as you could verify by pasting your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/, as recommended by the bash tag description (see the Important note near the top of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash).

Oops -- I stand corrected.

In bash, the operator < compare alphabetically in [[ ... ]]
To compare integer, you can use (( ... )) instead.
Remark that in (( ... )), variable should be used without $:
   if (( num1 <= 24 && num2 < 2 )); then

WARNING: (( ... )) can be unsafe and cause code injection. Do not use this unless you are sure the variable used are valid integers

What code injection? Variable names are recursively expanded until you get an integer, but as far as I know, expansions that produce anything other than another identifier or an integer simply produce a syntax error, not arbitrary code execution.

@chepner: here is an example var='BASH_VERSINFO[$(date >& 2)]' ; (( var == 2 )) -> if you run this, you will see that date is printed. I created this from mywiki.wooledge.org

Ah, right, array indices.

Note the usual guidance in the Answer Well-Asked Questions section of How to Answer regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".
